# How do you find the IP address of a specific mail server?

Tags: email, terminal, ip-address

For example, how can I find the IP address of the mail server @yahoo.com or @hotmail.com?

Is there a way to do this on terminal?

Thank you.

EDIT: I meant to say IP address of the mail server dealing email addresses ending with @yahoo.com or @hotmail.com

Comment: [DNS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System)

Comment: @H2CO3: Incorrect; that ends up looking up the address of the web server, not the mail server.

Comment: try `dig yahoo.com MX` and give one of the results to `dig` again

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[nslookup](http://linux.die.net/man/1/nslookup) is what you're after, or [dig](http://linux.die.net/man/1/dig). Since you want a mail server you'll want to add the option '-type=mx' (Mail eXchange).

```
nslookup -type=mx gmail.com
```

Comment: I get `;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached` when trying that query. Other queries works perfectly fine but some with the `-type=mx` options specified fails. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

First find the mailserver (might be multiples):

```bash
dig yahoo.com mx
```

Then request the IPv4 record:

```bash
dig <yahoo-mx> a
```

In some cases you can find the IP inside the SPF record:

```bash
dig <yahoo-mx> txt
```